# Not getting email id from resume using regex in java

Tags: java, regex

Im working on a cv parser, trying to retrieve values(name, email, mobile etc.) from a resume and keeping them in a `csv` file. Although I was able to retrieve the phone number but failed to retrieve email id. I am using the code mentioned below.

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("[@]");
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(text);
int i = 0;
int width = 0;

while (regexMatcher.find()) {
    if ((regexMatcher.start() - 10 > 0)
            && (regexMatcher.end() + 10 < text.length())) {

        width = 10;
        String[] substr = text.substring(
            regexMatcher.start() - width,
            regexMatcher.end() + width
        ).split(" ");

        for (int j = 0; j < substr.length; j++) {
            if (substr[j].contains("@")
                && (substr[j].contains(".com")
                    || substr[j].contains("@")
                    && substr[j].contains(".co.in")
                    || substr[j].contains(".net"))) {

                System.out.println(substr[j]);
                email = substr[j];
            }
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("NO MATCH");
    }
}

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d\\d\\d([,\\s])?\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d");
Matcher found = p.matcher(text);

if (found.find()) {
    mobile = found.group();
    System.out.println(mobile);

} else {
    System.out.println("NO MATCH1");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current approach appears to be find strings containing an at symbol `@`, and then somehow piece together the rest of the email address which appears around it.  But this defeats the purpose of using regular expressions in the first place.  In the code snippet below, I use the following regex to identify email address:

```
\\b[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}\\b
```

This should match most normal English email addresses.  I adapted it from [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html).

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}\\b");
Matcher found = p.matcher(text);
while (found.find()) {
    System.out.println(found.group(0));
}
```